# CentOS LiveCD Boot Prompt?

Tags: centos, boot, prompt, livecd

Booting CentOS LiveCD and received a prompt (see image). What is this for?[image]

Comment: This might be for mounting an encrypted partition. It looks weird without any text though.

Comment: Yeah... but anything typed into the text box is "dot-obfuscated", which lead me to think it was a password prompt.

Comment: That supports my hypothesis. Don't you have an encrypted partition on that disk?

Comment: AH... excellent hypothesis! The laptop I used to "try" this iso does have an encrypted HD. Thank you, TomasZ! I'll see what happens and let you know.

Comment: That was it, TomasZ! Thanks for the assistance! It would be nice if there were a text prompt to indicate this! Lol!

Comment: Yes, that's tricky. Please accept my answer so that the question is closed.

Comment: It doesn't look so. Are you sure? (Maybe it's some server sync.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a disk (or partition) decryption prompt.